# Integration test for SOAP based web service

Tags: java, web-services, testing

We have a webservice deployed at `https://<hostname>:<port>/app?wsdl`.

I need to set up a maven project to write integration testing suite for the apis. Are there any framework to do this kind of testing easily for a wsdl based web service?

Answer (score 1):

I used a time ago [Apache-CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html) for the integration tests.

It basically creates a Java client for a WebService, meaning interfaces and model classes are available in Java and you can use them as other normal Java implementation.

In order to generate the sources from a WSDL you need to run the CXF script giving the WSDL address. A Java package will be created with all classes / interfaces needed. In my case I just generated a JAR from the WS (check `-clientjar` parameter in the command line documentation).

Once the WebService changes you just need to regenerate the classes and interfaces again with the same command used at the first time and implement additional tests.

**Maven Integration**

To start using it within a maven project, you can check [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html). And the same functionality you have with the command line (in order to generate the java sources from a WSDL) you have with a maven plugin documented [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI offers a comprehensive suite for testing the the WSDL based web services. It has a nice UI and very well [integrated with the tools like Maven](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html). I would recommend SOAPUI.